# .net MS Excel interop add-in

Tags: .net, excel, ms-office, interop, add-in

Developed an Excel add-in using c#. To that Excel add-in I want to do some authentication. We are using cognito for authentication.

So in my excel ribbon I added a button which should open a browser tab upon click and do the oauth authentication and after receiving the token, I need that token in my Excel c#.

Is there any way this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider hosting a [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.7.2) control on a windows form. So, basically, you may give a popup window to a user for authentication.

I'd recommend that you use OAuth directly to authenticate against. You can google for how to use OAuth to automatically log a user into a system. There are a couple of different approaches so you'll have to decide the approach to use based upon what you are trying to accomplish.

Finally, you may consider your add-in as a regular .net application. You are free to use any .net based library in the code. There is no Excel specific things.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. Can you share some library or an article to move forward.

Comment: You can try google - https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=t7WKXNz8OMidsAe61oiwBw&q=generate+oauth+token+c%23&oq=oauth+authentication+c%23&gs_l=psy-ab.1.4.0i71l8.0.0..24849...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.x5NrAxXjglY